# Obtaining drag rectangle in isValidDropTarget

Tags: mxgraph

In mxgraph,a cell must be dragged onto another cell (its parent), but the location should be restricted. In particular, I want to avoid that cells dragged into the parent overlap each other.

I have overriden isValidDropTarget() and wrote my own version.
Here I want to check for the droptarget, if the area that is to be occupied by the cell to be dropped is free/not occupied by some other cell.

It is possible to find the coordinates and height/width of the cells in the parent, but I need to have to coordinates of the cell to be included. Specifically, I want to have the coordinates of the dragging rectangle

Answer (score 0):

In [isValidDropTarget()](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.isValidDropTarget) function you should have access to event from which you can get x,y poistion, and convert it to position on diagram, there is even helper for that: 
[convertPoint()](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/util/mxUtils-js.html#mxUtils.convertPoint):

> Converts the specified point (x, y) using the offset of the specified container and returns a new mxPoint with the result.

```
var pt = mxUtils.convertPoint(graph.container,
mxEvent.getClientX(evt), mxEvent.getClientY(evt));
```